# Контроль порядка выдачи результатов асинхронной операции

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, асинхронность

Я пишу программу, которая показывает превью изображений, добавляя их в ячейки таблицы. В соседних ячейках есть поля для имени, тегов и источника загружаемых фотографий, которые я также заполняю, после чего загружаю всю эту информацию вместе с файлами на сервер. Я использую объект `FileReader`, который в свою очередь записывает файлы методом `readAsDataUrl`. Но проблема в том, что этот метод работает асинхронно и как результат я вижу превью не в том порядке, в котором файлы будут загружены на сервер, а сами превью не соответствуют файлам, которые за ними стоят, получается перемешка. Это породило проблему, поскольку описания файла, которые вносит пользователь (имя, тег, источник) в результате не соответствуют картинке.

Вот как это выглядит (обратите внимание на описания). Процесс загрузки:

[image: загрузка]

Результат загрузки:

[image: результат]

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778843/order-issue-with-append-in-a-file-reader) люди уже поднимали и решили похожую проблему, но я не знаю, как применить эти идеи в моем случае, когда для каждого превью динамически создаются элементы таблицы. Прошу помощи.

Мой код:

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#fileUpload").on('change', function () {

        //Get count of selected files
        var countFiles = $(this)[0].files.length;
        var imgPath = $(this)[0].value;
        var extn = imgPath.substring(imgPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
        var image_holder = $("#image-holder");
        image_holder.empty();
        if (extn == "gif" || extn == "png" || extn == "jpg" || extn == "jpeg") {
            if (typeof(FileReader) != "undefined") {
                //loop for each file selected for uploaded.

                var newElem = document.createElement('table');
                newElem.id = 'tl';
                newElem.align = 'center';
                newElem.border = 0;

                for (var i = 0; i < countFiles; i++) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();


                    reader.onload = function (e) {

                        var newRow = newElem.insertRow(0);
                        var newCell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
                        newCell1.innerHTML = "<input type='text' class='form-control' " +
                            "placeholder='Source' name='source' style='margin: 15px'>";
                        var newCell2 = newRow.insertCell(0);
                        newCell2.innerHTML = "<input type='text' class='form-control' " +
                            "placeholder='Tags' name='tags' style='margin: 10px'>";
                        var newCell3 = newRow.insertCell(0);
                        newCell3.innerHTML = "<input type='text' class='form-control' " +
                            "placeholder='Name' name='name' style='margin-left: 5px'>";
                        var newCell4 = newRow.insertCell(0);

                        $("<img />", {
                            "src": e.target.result,
                            "class": "thumb-image"
                        }).appendTo(newCell4);

                    };

                    document.getElementById("image-holder").appendChild(newElem);
                    reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[i]);
                    image_holder.show();
                }
            } else {
                alert("This browser does not support FileReader.");
            }
        } else {
            alert("Please select images only");
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input id="fileUpload" name="file" multiple="multiple" type="file"/>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
        <br/>
        <div id="image-holder"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: В код вникать лень, но раз вам еще никто не ответил... Ваша задача (выстраивание очереди асинхронных операций) ну очень типична. Для решения таких задач обычно используются промисы:
http://learn.javascript.ru/promise. es-6 фича, поддержка "из коробки" достаточно высокая: http://caniuse.com/#search=promise. Если такой поддержки мало, то есть библиотека Bluebird, есть также промисы в jQuery (Deferred object), но со странным синтаксисом.

Comment: Однако повторюсь, вникать что происходит именно у вас в коде сейчас времени сейчас нет (может вечером если время будет и никто не овтетит), может быть именно у вас это оверхед. Но по описанию задача выглядит именно так, и нужно промисифицировать вызовы асинхронной операции (ваш файлридер). Проблема очень типовая, ну прям очень-очень типовая

Comment: Если ну прям не хотите вообще сторонних либ, и es6 не подходит, то каждую следующую асинхронную операцию отправляйте коллбеком из предыдущей. Но строго рекомендую так не делать, а один раз разобраться - меньше времени потратите

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для организации последовательной загрузки можно использовать [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Для этого загрузку изображения с помощью FileReader, можно вынести в функцию, которая будет возвращать Promise, который разрешится тогда, когда картинка загрузится.

Она может выглядеть так:

```
function loadImage(image){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function(e){ resolve(e.target.result); }
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(image);
    });
}
```

Используя [функцию `then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) можно подписаться на событие, которое произойдет, когда Prmoise перейдет в состояние готов.

например так:

```
loadImage().then(function(imageAsDataUrl){ ... });
```

Таким образом можно собрать цепочку асинхронных операций, которые будут выполняться друг за другом.

Итоговый вид может быть таким:

```
var queue = Promise.resolve();

[].reduce.call(this.files,function(queue, file, index){
    return queue.then(function(){
        return loadImage(file).then(function(imageAsDataUrl){
            var newRow = newElem.insertRow(0);
            var newCell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
            newCell1.innerHTML = "<input type='text' class='form-control' " +
                                 "placeholder='Source' name='source' style='margin: 15px'>";
            var newCell2 = newRow.insertCell(0);
            newCell2.innerHTML = "<input type='text' class='form-control' " +
                                 "placeholder='Tags' name='tags' style='margin: 10px'>";
            var newCell3 = newRow.insertCell(0);
            newCell3.innerHTML = "<input type='text' class='form-control' " +
                                 "placeholder='Name' name='name' style='margin-left: 5px'>";
            var newCell4 = newRow.insertCell(0);

            $("<img />", {
                "src": imageAsDataUrl,
                "class": "thumb-image"
            }).appendTo(newCell4);
        });
    });
}, Promise.resolve()).then(function(){
    // все картинки загрузились
    image_holder.show();
})
```

<sub>небольшое отступление: `$(this)[0]` это то же самое, что и `this`, можете проверить с помощью следующего выражения `$(this)[0] === this` вернет `true`.</sub>

Comment: огромное спасибо! Код работает с единственным багом — изображения теперь грузятся в порядке уже не рандомном, но противоположном первоначальному. Например, перед загрузкой я увидел котов в порядке один, три, два, пять и так же их и описал. Но после загрузки они отобразились в порядке пять, два, три, один, хотя описания остались на своих местах. Скриншот: http://prntscr.com/bas36u Можно ли влиять на порядок выдачи?

Comment: Разобрался, нужно применять reduceRight вместо reduce. Спасибо!

Comment: @OlegShankovskyi, проблема была не в `reduce`, а в том как строки вставляются, [insertRow(0)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow) вставляет в начало, поэтому кажется, что загружаются в обратном порядке

Comment: @Grundy приведённый код обеспечивает отображение картинок последовательно, по мере загрузки, или отображение происходит по окончании всех действий? У меня картинки загружаются в цикле for всё грузится и заполняется нормально, только загруженное отображается после окончания цикла for. если производить отладку , по шагам, то всё работает как надо - загрузилась картинка - появилась на экране.

Comment: @Вадим, картинки загружаются и показываются последовательно. Чтобы сказать, что именно не так с твоим кодом, его нужно увидеть. Можешь задать свой собственный вопрос и привести в нем пример.

Comment: @Grundy по твоему коду как с тобой можно проконсультироваться более детально?

Comment: @Вадим, если что-то быстрое, можно прям тут в комментариях спросить, если нет - лучше задать отдельный вопрос. Так же на SO есть чаты, например:  http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--

Comment: @Grundy мой код аналогичен тому что у ТС - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778843/order-issue-with-append-in-a-file-reader. там выведенная картинка, да и любая информция в DOM "не успевает прорисоваться" на экране во время цикла. в твоём коде как это устранено? решают ли эту проблему промисы?

Comment: @Вадим, там работает все так как и ожидается - все из-за асинхронности загрузки изображений. Вызвав readAsDataURL происходит загрузка, по ее окончании вызывается onload. Так как операция асинхронная, цикл не останавливается на время загрузки каждого изображения, поэтому в общем случае картинки могут добавляться в разнобой, а не по порядку.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48019/discussion-between--and-grundy).